# Where do I point my "Secure Base URL for Static View Files" for CDN in Magento 2?

Tags: cdn

Currently in Magento 2, deploying on live production we get the following:

```
/static/version1490119662/frontend/sss/default/en_US/Ves_Megamenu/css/styles.css
```

Sometimes not always in development and production we see the following:

```
/pub/static/frontend/sss/default/en_US/Ves_Megamenu/css/styles.css
```

So for my CDN, where should I point my origin too

```
/static or /pub
```

As I need to update my `Secure Base URL for Static View Files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remove version from url (like version1490119662), Try following way:

From **core_config_data** table set 'dev/static/sign' to 0

OR

From **Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Static Files Settings** Set 'Sign Static Files' to 'No'