# Magento 2: can't override js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides

I tried to override `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js`

For this in my custom module i have created under `Module/Namespace/view/frontend,` the file with the name `requirejs-config.js` with this content:

```
var config = {
    'map' :{
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default':'Module_Namespace/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default'
        }
    }
};
```

Under `Module/Namespace/view/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer`
i have created the file `default.js`

after i clean the cache on the console i have this err msg:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from '.../static/version1524065927/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Module_Namespace/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Does anyone know why this happend and is not working?

Note: I am on developer mode!

Comment: Is area (frontend) included in Module/Namespace/view/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer file path?

Comment: Check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167278/where-do-i-point-my-secure-base-url-for-static-view-files-for-cdn-in-magento-2

Comment: @Haritha thank you very much. that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below line in your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```